# test restful services and cleanup database after each test

Tags: java, jersey, automated-tests, rest-assured

i am using java,jersey and jap in my application.
 i want to test restful services and cleanup database after testing.
i searched for it and found rest assured framework. now when i test a service that it's responsibility is insert some data to database, i want to database stays in its state before calling rest service or cleanup test data from database.
i am new in this subjects and it's possible that i am going in wrong way. can any body help me for this problem?
or if i am in correct way; is there any approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Recommendation would be to use TestNG or similar testing framework than features *before* and *after* method annotation which enables you to do preparation of data that will be used in the test as well as cleanup after the test has finished.
Since you are interested in cleanup only, in *AfterMethod* you should make calls to database to delete data that was inserted during test execution.
You can read more about this topic on the [TestNG documentation page](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) to get you started.